# JavaFX - Insering login window into my main function

Tags: authentication, javafx

I am very much new to JavaFX, I started this week basing my knowledge solely off of small tutorials and sample projects learning the syntax. I have created a simple Table of Stock information that you can add and delete information in and would like to implement a login window to this program. I created the login window but am unsure of how to implement it in my main function properly.

Main.java

This contains my code for the stock application.

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    TableView<Stock> table;
    TextField symbolInput, nameInput, openingPriceInput, closingPriceInput, changeInPriceInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Stock Application");

        //Symbol column
        TableColumn<Stock, String> symbolColumn = new TableColumn<>("Symbol");
        symbolColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        symbolColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("symbol"));

        //Name column
        TableColumn<Stock, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        //Opening Price column
        TableColumn<Stock, Double> openingPriceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Opening Price");
        openingPriceColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        openingPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("openingPrice"));

        //Closing Price column
        TableColumn<Stock, Double> closingPriceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Closing Price");
        closingPriceColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        closingPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("closingPrice"));

        //Change in Price column
        TableColumn<Stock, Double> changeInPriceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Change in Price");
        changeInPriceColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        changeInPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("changeInPrice"));

        //Symbol input
        symbolInput = new TextField();
        symbolInput.setPromptText("Symbol");
        symbolInput.setMinWidth(100);

        //Name input
        nameInput = new TextField();
        nameInput.setPromptText("Name");

        //Opening Price input
        openingPriceInput = new TextField();
        openingPriceInput.setPromptText("Opening Price");

        //Closing Price input
        closingPriceInput = new TextField();
        closingPriceInput.setPromptText("Closing Price");

        //Change in Price Input
        changeInPriceInput = new TextField();
        closingPriceInput.setPromptText("Change in Price");

        //Button
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> addButtonClicked());
        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> deleteButtonClicked());

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(symbolInput, nameInput, openingPriceInput, closingPriceInput, changeInPriceInput, addButton, deleteButton);

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getStock());
        table.getColumns().addAll(symbolColumn, nameColumn, openingPriceColumn, closingPriceColumn, changeInPriceColumn);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(table, hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    //Add button clicked
    public void addButtonClicked(){
        Stock Stock = new Stock();
        Stock.setSymbol(symbolInput.getText());
        Stock.setName(nameInput.getText());
        Stock.setOpeningPrice(Double.parseDouble(openingPriceInput.getText()));
        Stock.setClosingPrice(Double.parseDouble(closingPriceInput.getText()));
        Stock.setChangeInPrice(Double.parseDouble(changeInPriceInput.getText()));
        table.getItems().add(Stock);
        symbolInput.clear();
        nameInput.clear();
        openingPriceInput.clear();
        closingPriceInput.clear();
        changeInPriceInput.clear();
    }

    //Delete button clicked
    public void deleteButtonClicked(){
        ObservableList<Stock> StockSelected, allStocks;
        allStocks = table.getItems();
        StockSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        StockSelected.forEach(allStocks::remove);
    }

    //Get all of the Stocks
    public ObservableList<Stock> getStock(){
        ObservableList<Stock> stocks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        stocks.add(new Stock("AMZN", "Amazon", 571, 576.4583, 5.4583));
        stocks.add(new Stock("EBAY", "eBay", 24.10, 23.7318 , -0.3682));
        stocks.add(new Stock("AAPL", "Apple Inc.", 103.91, 104.516, 0.606));
        stocks.add(new Stock("SNEJF", "Sony Corp", 24.375, 24.375, 0.00));
        stocks.add(new Stock("SBUX", "Starbucks", 58.32, 58.86, 0.54));
        return stocks;
    }


}
```

Controller.java

This contains the code for my login window.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Label labelStatus;

    @FXML
    private TextField textUsername;

    @FXML
    private TextField textPassword;

    public void Login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        if (textUsername.getText().equals("CS1113") && textPassword.getText().equals("Section011")) {
            labelStatus.setText("Login is Successful");
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } else {
            labelStatus.setText("Login failed!!");
        }
    }

}
```

The accompanying FXML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="buttonLogin" layoutX="113.0" layoutY="224.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login">
      <font>
        <Font size="18.0" fx:id="x1" />
      </font>
    </Button>
    <TextField fx:id="textUsername" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="68.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="username" />
    <PasswordField id="txtPassword" fx:id="textPassword" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="password" />
    <Label fx:id="labelStatus" font="$x1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefWidth="272.0" text="Status" textAlignment="LEFT" textFill="#cc0000" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I am sure there is an easier way to implement a large amount of my code or an easier way to implement some of the methods or functions I have created.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The application class is the entry point, not the controller. If you want the login window to be shown first, you have to show the login in the `start` method first and make sure not to show the main window until the login was successful.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you can achieve this. When you load from an FXML file, you are loading a Parent node. So, in order to swap from one screen to another, you can either set the Parent node of the existing scene to be the new Parent node, or you can create a new Scene based on the new node and set the new Scene on the Stage of the main application. You may need to expose some methods that will allow you to do this or ensure that your screens have access to the Stage or Scene objects created in the main application class.

This isn't too bad a tutorial in how to implement a possible screen management aspect to your JavaFX application: https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1. I rolled my own to cater for FXML and manually created screens, inspired by this initial stab at it.